# I get a System.NullReferenceException On the part of code where it Clicks the button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I get a System.NullReferenceException On the part of code where it Clicks the button.
I have problem that `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Giriş Yap").InvokeMember("click")`.
Meanwhile I am not coder , i found that code in web. I want do auto facebook login code.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Giriş Yap").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This isn't even C++/CLI. This is Visual Basic.

Comment: Giriş Yap is turkish word. it is Login mean.

Comment: Looks like the id "Giriş Yap" doesn't exist.